# error in block processing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to apply dct and quantization to 8*8 blocks like this.

```
img = imread('frames/frm001.png');
ycbcr = rgb2ycbcr(img);


y = ycbcr(:,:,1);

func = @dct2;
whos func;

d1 = blkproc(y,[8 8],func);

qmtx =     [16 11 10 16 24 40 51 61; 
            12 12 14 19 26 58 60 55;
            14 13 16 24 40 57 69 56; 
            14 17 22 29 51 87 80 62;
            18 22 37 56 68 109 103 77;
            24 35 55 64 81 104 113 92;
            49 64 78 87 103 121 120 101;
            72 92 95 98 112 100 103 99];
d1 = ceil(d1);
whos d1;
c = @(block_struct) (block_struct.data) ./ qmtx;        
d2 = blkproc(d1,[8,8], c );
whos d2;
```

For this I'm getting the following error

Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
Error in @(block_struct)(block_struct.data)./qmtx
Error in blkproc (line 103)
firstBlock = feval(fun,x,params{:});
Error in dct (line 28)
d2 = blkproc(d1,[8,8], c );

What might have gone wrong..?

Comment: I'm expecting the quantized matrix...

Comment: are you sure you have a variable called `block_struct` and that it has a field called `data`?

Comment: Yes..its in built in matlab

Comment: d1 is a matrix and not a struct. Just do c = @(data) (data) ./ qmtx;